# C++: Forward declaration of class member (variable)

Tags: c++

Is it possible to forward declare a class member variable? I want to do something like the following (But it doesn't work):

```
class myClass;
bool myClass::myvar;

void main()
{
    myClass* aaa;
    ...
    aaa->myvar = false;
}
```

In this example, myvar is a boolean member of myClass.

Comment: To understand why you can't, try to figure out where to store the new value of `*aaa`'s  member  using only the information that such a member exists.

Comment: It's also not good from a design point of view because modifying internal data break encapsulation.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't. Imagine the class is scattered across different translation units this way.
What members will it have then? And what will be the object layout?

That's intractable.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use set/get methods in this case. Then you don't expose your internal data to the outside world.

In the header of myClass:

```
class myClass
{
    public: setMyVar(const bool& value);
    public: inline const bool& getMyVar() const;

    private: bool myVar;
};
```

In your implementation:

```
class myClass;

void main()
{
    myClass* aaa;
    ...
    aaa->setMyVar(false);
}
```

Comment: It seems like the point of the question is to use the data of the class without needing to include the header for the class, but in your case `setMyVar` is still not accessible without including a full definition of the class (and not just a forward declare as asked for).

Comment: Ahh, most probably I missunderstood the point. All data types and declarations must be known to the compiler in each translation unit, and the forward declaration does not substitute this. So, that in your particular case the header must be included.